# Proper way to get the latest doc (by timestamp) created with a specific field value?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I am still learning cloudant and need a little help to figure out what will be the right tool to use to get the latest document (based on timestamp in the document) with a specific field value.

I have read through the views documentation and understand  I can create a view whose key is an array with data ["field-value","timestamp"]? And then at query time, query by the key with descending order and limit the docs to 1? or is there a better way to do it? I will be using partitioned db.

Sample data when queried for documents with key:"k1":

```
   {
     "id": "55e9fd410b0df870409e0d92bf6a8318",
     "key": "k1",
     "time": "2019-08-06T19:11:16.556Z"
   },
   {
     "id": "77a3ba0b77f1c740f68bac46a2a307ee",
     "key": "k1",
     "time": "2019-08-06T19:11:16.539Z"
   }
```

Desired output:

```
{
     "id": "55e9fd410b0df870409e0d92bf6a8318",
     "key": "k1",
     "time": "2019-08-06T19:11:16.556Z"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that in several ways. The most flexible one is to create a view that emits a vector-valued key containing the key and yyyy, mm, dd or whichever bits you care about from the time stamp:

```
function (doc) {
  var d = new Date(doc.timestamp);
  emit([
    doc.product_id,
    d.getFullYear(), 
    d.getMonth()+1, 
    d.getDate()], null);
  }
}
```

With a reduce of say `_count` you can then also aggregate over time. This approach is described well in an old [blog post](https://blog.cloudant.com/2011/01/13/mapreduce-from-the-basics-to-the-actually-useful.html) from Mike Miller.

If you don't care about aggregation you can either just emit an epoch second as the key, or construct time-sortable ids, as suggested by Glynn Bird in another Cloudant [blog post](https://blog.cloudant.com/2018/08/24/Time-sortable-document-ids.html).